# picturebox click event fires before the picturebox's contextmenu menuitem click

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, picturebox

I have a PictureBox.Click event and I also have a PictureBox.ContextMenu -- when I click on a menu item within the context menu, it fires the PictureBox.Click event first, then the event attached to the menu item.

This is not what I want.  Is there a way to fire the menu item event only (or at least, first)?

Comment: How do you open the context menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is no `e.Handled` parameter you can use a flag to abort the `Click` code:

```
bool flag = false;

private void pb_target_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pb_target_MouseDown RIGHT");
        flag = true;
    }

    else flag = false;
}

private void pb_target_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (flag) { flag = false; return; }

    Console.WriteLine("pb_target_MouseClick");
}
```

Comment: Very nice, didn't think to trap the right-click.

Thank you so much!